# SQLLDR via Batch File

Tags: batch-file, sql-loader

I have created a batch file with SQLLDR commands to load contents of a txt file into Oracle table. The SQLLDR command is below

```
SQLLDR USERID=USERNAME/PASSWORD@DATABASE 
CONTROL='File_Load.CTL', LOG='TESTLOG.LOG', BAD='TESTBAD.BAD', 
DATA='TESTDATA.txt'
```

When I execute the batch file into CMD below is what I get in return.

CONTROL =

Not sure what's wrong here but its not allowing me to automate the task for me.

Can anybody please help me here?

Thanks
Yash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it all on one line, remove the commas and single quotes. [RTFM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_params.htm#i1004590)

Also I believe you can break long command lines in a Windows batch file with the circumflex line continuation character like this:

```
SQLLDR USERID=USERNAME/PASSWORD@DATABASE ^
CONTROL=File_Load.CTL LOG=TESTLOG.LOG BAD=TESTBAD.BAD ^ 
DATA=TESTDATA.txt
```

Comment: Hi Gary_W, thanks a ton, it seems its working as the load is running right now. Thanks a lot once again.